# Connecting qt client application to a database on server

Tags: qt, sqlite, network-programming

I am making a small project where there is a qt client application  and basic server application written in c++. I am able to connect between two different computers through my application (over SSL, Socket). Now I want to connect my client application to access a sqlite database which is on server.

For example. lets say my client application is a simple login form. When user press Login button then I want my application to access the sqlite database on server, and verify whether the details are valid.

Above a just a example fr explanation. I know I can do the above thing in various other ways but I want the above functionality for something different.I searched a lot over internet but unable to find a good example or explanation. Please through some insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite data is stored in a single file, and there's no database server running on top of it. So it does not have any network connection capability. A very simple solution is to make the SQLite database file available on a network in some way like sharing it's directory.

There are other options which use third party libraries :

- [netSQLite](http://atensoft.net/dev/sqlite3.php) : a client/server solution running over TCP/IP with SQLite3 at its core.
- [Navicat](http://www.navicat.com/products/navicat-for-sqlite) : enables remote SQLite connection although it is not free.
- [SQLiteServer](http://sqliteserver.xhost.ro/index.html): a multithreaded TCP/IP server for SQLite
- [SQLiteDBMS](http://sqlitedbms.sourceforge.net/): a database management server for SQLite. It allows an sqlite3 process to be accessed via a TCP/IP network.

Comment: It seems that TS rather wants to write some analogue of SQLiteServer/SQLiteDBMS of his own.